# What is the difference and pro and cons uploading documents to Rest api Salesforce in binary format or base64

Tags: apex, rest-api, files, contentdocument, base64

I have been reading several articles about uploading documents trough Rest api to Salesforce but could not find  the overal difference between binary format or base64.

The main questions I have.

1. Is/are there specific reasons to chose 1 above the other for a project.
2. Am I dependent on what format is delivered in the call.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can upload in binary format, do so. If your source platform cannot use binary, then use base64. Base64-encoded data is approximately 33% larger, meaning longer upload times, more bandwidth used, and a lower maximum [file size for non-multipart uploads](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm).

> You can insert or update blob data using a non-multipart message, but you are limited to 50 MB of text data or 37.5 MB of base64–encoded data.

Consider the following:

```
Plain Text
Hello World

Base64-encoded Text
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=
```

As you can see, the data is already longer, and this is a very short message. The longer the message, the more "waste" that will be involved.

There is literally no advantage to using base64-encoded data; this option is provided only for greater compatibility with systems that do not support binary file uploads.

Comment: Another consideration is how the uploaded file is subsequently used - if it is only ever sent to systems that require base64 encoded data that saves time with server-side conversion (at the cost of slower initial upload). I do agree, however, that generally speaking it is better to keep the data "raw" and treat it that way in all places, transforming on demand when required.